# Does surveymonkey have a javascript library to track if the user clicks on "No thanks" or "Give feedback"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, survey, surveymonkey

I'm working on adding a survey(monkey) to a website.

I need to execute an action when the user clicks on "No Thanks".

Is there a js library to do it properly or i should go with the hacky solution: bind the onClick() event for this button.

Here is the surveymonkey anchor that acts as a button:

```
<a smcx-btn-secondary="" href="#" class="smcx-btn smcx-btn-secondary smcx-pull-left">No Thanks</a>
```

As you can see, the selectors might change in the future, so the hacky solution might stop working in the near future.

Comment: No we don't a JavaScript SDK to be able to do something like that, and I'm not sure if there is anything in the pipeline for it either.

Comment: Thanks akand074. What would be the best selector to match the onClick for this button, with this i mean which one is not likely to change.

Comment: Well, we can't say for certain that anything there won't change, and there doesn't seem to be any unique selector to that link. So maybe `.smcx-btn` but I'm not really familiar with that part of the code base but it seems clearly not designed to be open for modifying events on them by developers.

I don't see it changing any time soon but I would keep on the lookout with some sort of test for a change so you can handle that. I'll pass the concern over.